# How to get lenght of list with if-else (Python)

Tags: python, list

If wanna check if the lenght of a list is 80 (then print'lenght is 80'), if not it should print ('length is not 80'). How do I integrate this? I tried the following:

```
len_lst = range(80)

def lenghti (len_lst):
    if len(len_lst) = 80:
        return ('lenght is 80')
    else:
        return ('lenght is not 80')
print (lenghti)
```

Comment: `=`should be `==`. `=` is the assignment operator, `==` is the equality comparison operator. Then, you'll need to call `lenghti`: `print(lenghti(len_lst))`.

Comment: and you need to **call** the function `lenghti`... e.g. `print(lenghti()len_lst)`. also note that `range` is not a list (although `len(range(...))` works.

Answer (score 2):

There were two errors in this code:

```
len_lst = range(80)

def lenghti(len_lst):
    if len(len_lst) == 80: # = is assignment operator, you need to check a condition 
                           # so you need ==
        return ('length is 80')
    else:
        return ('length is not 80')
print(lenghti(len_lst)) # You need to call the function with an argument
```

Comment: I'd add for clarification that the local name of the argument (in the function) need not be the same as the name out of the function. As the original poster seems to be a beginner, it might be a good idea to emphasize on this with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```py
def length_of_list(list):
    """
    This function prints "The length is 80" if the list has 80 elements otherwise print "The length is not 80"
    """
    if len(list) == 80:
        print("The length is 80")
    else:
        print("The length is not 80")
```

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to propose using the name of a built-in function as a variable name